# How to install MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, matlab

How to install MATLAB in Ubuntu 14.04? I searched in USC, but it only has some extension for MATLAB.

Comment: [Matlab on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB)

Comment: @KasiyA That page is *very* outdated. Quote: "MATLAB R2012a users are strongly encouraged to install R2012a on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS or Ubuntu 10.10 for best results." -- do you really want OP to follow a post like that?

Comment: @kraxor Besides what version of Ubuntu (and possibly MATLAB) should be used, are those instructions otherwise problematically out of date?

Answer (score 6):

Matlab isn't included in the Software Center because it's a closed source and proprietary program. However, just downloading the installer for Ubuntu (R2013a specifically) from MathWorks and using all default settings worked fine for me on 64-bit 14.04.

If you downloaded it, you'll have to unzip it first. If you have an installation CD or DVD it should auto-mount when you insert it.

Then just browse to the correct folder in a terminal using `cd` and execute:

`./install`

If you want to install it to someplace like `/opt` you'll have to preface that command with `sudo`.

See also:

- [Install using your MathWorks account](http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-mathworks-software.html)
- [Install using a key file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/install/ug/install-and-activate-without-an-internet-connection.html)