# Installing MATLAB error: can't find glnx86 folder

Tags: mount, software-installation, iso, matlab

I am attempting to install MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509902/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-14-04).

1. I downloaded the MATLAB 2015a ISO file.
2. I then typed these commands into the terminal:

> ```
> $ sudo mkdir /usr/local/iso
> $ cd ~/Downloads
> $ sudo mount -o loop R2015a-glnxa64.iso /usr/local/iso
> mount: block device /home/matta/Downloads/R2015a-glnxa64.iso is
> write-protected, mounting read-only
> $ cd /usr/local/iso
> $ ./install
> ./install: 1: eval: /usr/local/iso/bin/glnx86/install_unix: not found
> ```

The glnx86 folder does not exist but there is a glnxa64 folder in that location with an 'install unix' file inside. I tried modifying the install file but everything is read-only so I can't.

I have been using linux for 2 days now so sorry for any glaring errors.

Comment: Are you trying to install it on a 32-bit Linux system? AFAIK that's not supported: see [System Requirements – Release R2015a](http://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/current_release/index.html?sec=linux)

Comment: @steeldriver. YES I AM!! Thank you very much. I looked at that page several times but never at the title bit where it states that. Thank you very much. I guess that's the answer if you want to put it on.