# Matlab installation using mathwork account fails to find

Tags: matlab

I am trying to install Matlab on Ubuntu using my account on Mathwork. I remember installing in the same way on Windows properly, but here on Ubuntu it fails to proceed... It should have proceeded without this error, because I did the same installation on Windows previously. The error says that it failed to create a folder. I wonder what might be the case here.  I will provide the image for clarification.[image]

If this situation is familiar to anybody, can you advice what to do further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MATLAB on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/509902/how-to-install-matlab-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: When you are running `./install` as regular user, you can't write to a system folder. If you like to write to `/usr/local/...` you should execute `sudo ./install` which will run `./install` as `root`

Comment: @Yaron I think it helped, the process is on...
Thank you!

Comment: happy to hear that it helped! enjoy :)

Comment: @Yaron, well, it did work, I can't use it.  It's produced 
`License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -9
Your username does not match the username in the license file. 
To run MATLAB on this computer, you must run the Activation client to reactivate your license.`
Do you know any solution to this?